# How to mapping an Object with ArrayList with Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, mapping, retrofit, retrofit2

I have trying to make this call works, but always the return is null (and the problem isn't on API). If I try to make a Call  (Object with ArrayList), the callback is successful but the body is null. How I mapping this with Retrofit2 (I'm new with Retrofit2)? This is my service:

```
  @GET("farms/abstract")
  Call<Farm> getFarmList(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

The API response:

```
{
    "farms": [
        {
            "id": "0fc2b30c-4500-c399-4171-e2809373e281",
            "name": "Areado"
        },
        {
            "id": "81041a28-1193-4310-b616-fabcabdf63d1",
            "name": "Fazenda 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I use jsonschema2pojo.org to make my classes:

```
public class Farm {
    @SerializedName("farms")
    @Expose
    private List<FarmList> farms;

    public Farm() {
    }

    public List<FarmList> getFarms() {
        return farms;
    }

    public void setFarms(List<FarmList> farms) {
        this.farms = farms;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Farm{" +
                "farms=" + farms +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My FarmList.class:

```
public class FarmList {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public FarmList() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FarmList{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

RetrofitConfig:

```
public class RetrofitConfig {
    private final Retrofit retrofit;

    public RetrofitConfig() {
        this.retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                /*URL API*/
                .baseUrl("API_URL")

                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

                .build();
    }

    public LoginService getLogin() {
        return this.retrofit.create(LoginService.class);
    }

    public FarmService getFarm() {
        return this.retrofit.create(FarmService.class);
    }

    public FarmService getFarmList() {
        return this.retrofit.create(FarmService.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only pass the `endpoint` in your call method `@GET("abstract")`
If you have not created a `RetrofigConfig` Class. I'd suggest first you make that, there you can define `Baseurl` for your apis

If your `url` is dynamic then you can make the call like this

```
@GET
Call<HashMap<String, String>> getLocationWithUrl(@Url String url);
```

Comment: I have a Retrofit Config. I have updated my question and put then

Comment: @GabrielJúniordeSouza did you try just passing the `endpoint`

Comment: Yes, if I pass only the '/abstract' on call: Response{protocol=h2, code=403, message=, url=URL_LINK/abstract}

Comment: How I pass the @Header in your call example? Because I need this to make my call works

Comment: Jus like you have done `@Header("Authorization") String token`

Comment: I try this:  @GET()
    "Call<HashMap<String, String>> getFarmList(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Url String url);", the call works but my response body is: "detail -> Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Answer (score 1):

I have tested with mocky.io http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ed4f4b23300006500f7a5e0.
and it's working fine, seems your header created a problem. Make your API call like below

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("farms/abstract")
Call<Farm> getFarmList();
```

And create a Function for Auth In your RetrofitConfig like below

```
 public static Retrofit createServiceWithAuth(Context mContext,String token) {



        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new AuthorizationInterceptor(token))
                .build();

        this.retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("API_URL")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient)
                .build();

        return  this.retrofit;
    }
```

Add this Class

```
public class AuthorizationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private String authorizationKey;

    public AuthorizationInterceptor() {

    }

    public AuthorizationInterceptor(String token) {
        this.authorizationKey = token;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        final Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .addHeader("token",authorizationKey)
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }


    public String getAuthorizationKey() {
        return authorizationKey;
    }

    public void setAuthorizationKey(String authorizationKey) {
        this.authorizationKey = authorizationKey;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove the Retrofit2 and use the OkHttpClient/ObjectMapper:

```
 private void okHttpFarmClient() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        String url = "URL/farms/abstract";

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken)
                .build();
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull okhttp3.Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull okhttp3.Call call, @NonNull okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    String farmResponse = response.body().string();
                    farm = objectMapper.readValue(farmResponse, Farm.class);
                    try {
                        farm = objectMapper.readValue(farmResponse, Farm.class);
                        farmListArrayList = farm;
                        createFarmRecyclerView();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    FazendaActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d("OkHttpRun", "run: " + farmResponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```